# HTML object tag fallback method

Tags: html, object, rdp

I am building a page, where i need to display an RDP client ActiveX object in a browser. This obvisously only works in IE+Windows, so i need to make sure that other browsers get an error message.

About the object tag, w3c writes:

> If the user agent is not able to render the object for whatever
>   reason (configured not to, lack of resources, wrong architecture,
>   etc.), it must try to render its contents.

So i am doing like this:

```
<object
    id="MsRdpClient"
    onreadystatechange="TryConnect();"
    codebase="msrdp.cab#version=5,1,2600,1050"
    classid="CLSID:9059f30f-4eb1-4bd2-9fdc-36f43a218f4a">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "failure.aspx";
    </script>
</object>
```

However, IE (9) renders the content of the object tag, even though the objects loads. Is this a bug in IE?

What can i do instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a known issue in IE9 but hasn't been fixed yet. Read about it [on the msdn site.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622942%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I came to the same conclusion. I'll probably be able to get around it, but altering the connection js.